# Android web view invoking and clicking element

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, webview

I was working on a mobile app, the app plays music from some website using [`jplayer`](http://jplayer.org) and changes from one song to another **with out no user interaction**, my first trail to build the app using [`phonegap`](http://build.phonegap.com) which failed because HTML5 media tags are not allowed to start automatically on mobile devices because of bandwidth issue,the user must click some button to play the media so i am trying some thing new as below,

1. Create a native android app with a **webView**
2. Set the url of the webview url to a file in **Assets** folder
3. After the page is loaded and the media is ready to be played, programmatically click on the play button which is in the webview using java so that it can start playing

I have given the play button in the webview an id of `playbtn`

#### My java code

I have created a button in order to execute the clicking event of the playbtn.

```
    final WebView wv;  
    Button playbtn;
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    playbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    wv.clearCache(true);
    wv.clearHistory();
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
    playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // the toast shows up
            wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                    "l=document.getElementById('playbtn');"+
                    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
                    "})()");
          //nothing happens here
        }
    });
```

I don't thing using JavaScript interface will work, since there is no user interaction, is there any way to accomplish the clicking of the `playbtn` programmatically?

#### Update

Once playback has started clicking the button is now resuming the music.